# Видео как первая часть сложных слов

Tags: орфография

Какое из этих написаний, на ваш взгляд, можно признать верным?

*Видео-прикол, видеоприкол, видео прикол*

В интернете раздельное написание.

Но в Орфографическом словаре Лопатина о раздельном написании не сказано.

**видео… - первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно,** но: *видео-арт, видео-ввод-вывод, видео-вход-выход, видео-диско-клуб, видео-компакт-диск, видео-конференц-связь, видео-пресс-конференция, видео-стриптиз-клуб, видео-ЭЭГ-мониторинг*

Comment: _Серж:

В интернете раздельное написание._ === Разве?

Comment: slava1947,  по крайней мере, другого написания мне не удалось найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: **видеоприкол.**

Из словаря:

**ВИДЕОСЮЖЕТ**, м. Тема, предмет изображения телевизионной передачи.

**ПРИКОЛ**,  м. Жарг. Шутка, розыгрыш.

**ВИДЕО**...  Первая часть сложных слов. Обозначает отнесённость чего-л. к воспроизведению изображения с магнитного или иного носителя. Видеоаппаратура, видеозал, видеоинформация, видеосвязь,

**Видеоприкол ― это видеосюжет на юмористическую тему,** нет причин писать это слово через дефис.

Answer (score 2):

Слитно, кроме тех слов (с [видеоартом](http://dictionary2.com/orfo/page/videoart.php) я бы поспорила), которые состоят из трёх корней.

**Большой толковый словарь**

**ВИДЕО...** [от лат. videre - видеть] ***Первая часть сложных слов.*** Обозначает отнесённость чего-л. к воспроизведению изображения с магнитного или иного носителя. *Видеоаппаратура, видеозал, видеоинформация, видеосвязь.*

---

**[Видеотрансляция, макроэкономика и мини-юбка: как правильно писать сложные слова?](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/45657-videotranslyatsiya--makroekonomika-i-mini-yubka-kak-pravilno-pisat-slozhnye-slova/)**

> ...В случае, когда сложное слово представляет собой комбинацию
>   вышеозначенных частей, все слово пишется слитно:
>   аудиовидеооборудование, фотовидеосистема. Корректно использовать и
>   альтернативный вариант: аудио- и видеооборудование, фото- и
>   видеосистема.
>
> Вместе с тем недопустимо слитное написание с приставкой или первой
>   частью сложного слова, если вторая часть слова содержит дефис. Слитное
>   написание должно заменяться дефисным, в результате чего возникает
>   написание с двумя дефисами: видео-конференц-связь (сравните:
>   конференц-связь и видеосвязь).

См. также [Толковый Словарь Ефремовой](http://dictionary2.com/efremova/page/video___.php).

---

[...Уличный фестиваль видеоарта «ПУСТО» — московский фестиваль видеоарта.](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE/%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE)

[...По этому архиву можно изучать историю видеоарта: как он появился на свет, как развивался и менялся.](http://www.peterburg.biz/19-maya-31-yanvarya-masshtabnaya-programma-nemetskiy-videoart-v-russkom-m.html)